# Ошибка "undefined reference to glViewport" в QtCreator

Tags: opengl, qtcreator

скачал библиотеки, запускаю код - и первая же функция выдает ошибку...
и дальше все так...

> /home/chame/test/main.cpp:9: ошибка: undefined reference to `glViewport'

как исправить?

Comment: ну очевидно что соответсвующая библиотека отсутсвует в настройках линкера или у вас её вобще нету нигде на диске ... мало информации дали о проблеме

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка означает, что вы забыли указать в свойствах проекта на необходимость подключения библиотеки `libopengl32.a`. Именно она реализует `glViewport()` наряду со всеми остальными функциями OpenGL.

Подключить её можно следующим образом:

- для qmake:

  ```
  LIBS += -lopengl32 <прочие библиотеки>
  ```
- для CMake:

  ```
  find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
  include_directories(${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries(ваш_проект ${OpenGL_LIBRARIES})
  ```